# Using SOAP web services and access client request parameters in php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, soap

I am new to SOAP web services and trying to learn them,i have a project developed in laravel  framework  where a client sends the request in form of a SOAP message,how do i parse the SOAP request and get to access the variables passed in the request for  further processing?

Answer (score 2):

To process the soap request you need soap_client.

You can do it in 3 ways,

1) Use PHP `SoapClient()` function

```
<?php

$wsdl   = "https://<your_web_service_url>?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));  // The trace param will show you errors stack

// web service input params
$request_param = array(
    "param1" => $value1,
    "param2" => $value2,
    "param3" => $value3,
    "param4" => $value4
);

try
{
    $responce_param = $client->webservice_methode_name($request_param);
   //$responce_param =  $client->call("webservice_methode_name", $request_param); // Alternative way to call soap method
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{ 
    echo "<h2>Exception Error!</h2>"; 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

?>

2) NuSoap library to create instance of soap client
For NuSoap library check,
[NuSoap Library and soap client Example](https://github.com/sagarsdeshmukh/nusoap/blob/master/README.md)

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$wsdl   = "http://<your_web_service_url>?wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');

// Input params
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";

// In this demo, we use json data , you can use any other data format for same
$json     = '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}';

$client->setCredentials($username, $password);
$error = $client->getError();

if ($error)
{
    echo $error; die();
}

$action = "webservice_methode_name"; // webservice method name

$result = array();

if (isset($action))
{
    $result['response'] = $client->call($action, $json);
}

echo "<h3>Output : </h3>";
echo $result['response'];
echo "<h2>Request</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response</h2>";
echo "<pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>";
```

?>

3) Using curl you can call Soap webservice

```
<?php
$webservice_url = "https://<your_web_service_url>";

$request_param = array(
                    "param1" => $value1,
                    "param2" => $value2,
                    "param3" => $value3,
                    "param4" => $value4
                );

$ch = curl_init($webservice_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_param);
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
// time allowed to connect to server 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30); 
// time allowed to process curl call 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<username>:<password>");

/* ** Alternative way to set username and password ** */
//$headers = array(
//    'Content-Type:application/xml',
//    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("<username>:<password>")
//);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);

$result = $data;

if ($result === FALSE) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n", curl_errno($ch),
    htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)));
}

curl_close ($ch);
echo "Responce : ".$data;
```

?>

Comment: in the params i see you pass is that the request parameters that are being sent in the request?

Comment: and how do i print out the parameters from the web service request

Comment: yes, the in first method (Using SoapClient() method) the "$request_param" is the actual web-service request param.

Comment: If you want to print web-service request (soap header)  Do simply,  echo "REQUEST:" . $client->__getLastRequest() ;

Comment: $req= $client->credit($request_param);
  var_dump($req);

Comment: please not its a client who is sending the request in SOAP format,all i need is to be able to caption the request parameters he sent.am acting as the server here.

Comment: I admit my fault in understanding your question. you are at SOAP server end. and want to process SOAP web service request. am i right? As per details you provided here, you already have web-service ready in Laravel framework. correct ?

Comment: If web service is already there, then please check is it using Nusoap library OR native php SoapServer() method to initiate SOAP server instance?

Comment: ,am not able to tell if its using Nusoap or Native PHP ,i have the WSDL file provided to me.here is a sample of how one request will be

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="url" xmlns:ns="url" xmlns:ns1="url" xmlns:ns2="url" xmlns:ns3="url">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:statusRequest>
         <ns:security>
            <ns1:login>?</ns1:login>
            <ns1:password>?</ns1:password>
         </ns:security>
         <ns:hsTransactionId>?</ns:hsTransactionId>
         <ns2:vendorSpecificFields>
            <ns3:vsf>
               <ns3:vendorId>?</ns3:vendorId>
               <ns3:fieldId>?</ns3:fieldId>     
          </ns3:vsf>
         </ns2:vendorSpecificFields>
      </ns:statusRequest>

Comment: so from the above sample files i need to access the elements such as hsTransactionId,password sent, login and an other field that is inside the request sent.thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you are very right i will be the soap server in this case trying to process a SOAP request and send necessary response to the client. for the web service i just have the expected WSDL file.

Comment: Please check below link that may help you to solve your issue, http://www.ilovephp.net/php/soap-web-services-using-nusoap-library/